# Is there any difference between the way beanManager.getBeans work in CDI 1.0 versus CDI 1.2?

Tags: cdi, vaadin7

beanManager.getBeans(abc.class, new AnnotationLiteral

returns result set in CDI 1.0 but don't return results in CDI 1.2.

Are there any changes which need to be done?

Answer (score 1):

CDI 1.2 introduced some [major changes related to the bean discovery mode](http://www.cdi-spec.org/news/2014/04/14/CDI-1_2-released/#rethinking-the-default-bean-discovery-mode). It may be the cause of your issue.

Since CDI 1.2, the [bean discovery mode](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#default_bean_discovery) defaults to `annotated`, that allows CDI to be activated by default in Java EE 7 without the `beans.xml` file.

See the following quote that explains how beans can be defined since CDI 1.2:

> [**2.5.1. Bean defining annotations**](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#bean_defining_annotations)
>
> A bean class may have a bean defining annotation, allowing it to be
>   placed anywhere in an application, as defined in [Bean Archives](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#bean_archive). A bean
>   class with a bean defining annotation is said to be an implicit bean.
>
> The set of bean defining annotations contains:
>
> - `@ApplicationScoped`, `@SessionScoped`, `@ConversationScoped` and
>     `@RequestScoped` annotations,
> - all other normal scope types,
> - `@Interceptor` and `@Decorator` annotations,
> - all stereotype annotations (i.e. annotations annotated with
>     `@Stereotype`),
> - and the `@Dependent` scope annotation.

Comment: <bean-discovery-mode> is set to all, so it should ideally discover all beans. if I change abc.class to object.class then it's discovering some beans.

Comment: I found the issue. It was not due to any CDI issue. It was more related to class loading boundaries. I was trying access beans in a separate jar outside my war. Solved it by adding the classpath to Manifest.mf. Thanks for your suggestion.